# Remove Vuetify from View Source

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to remove v-application from view-source or obfuscate the CSS or change the tags

Or is done like that to promote the UI framework n let other devs know that's what your using?

Comment: It's not let to promote anything, it's a way of not having a collision if you use several frameworks at the same time. Indeed, having `v-application` in Vuetify and Bootstrap would raise a problem. Why do you want to obfuscate at all? Web is a public and open space.

Comment: Hey, sent you a message via your DM on twitter